# filting through 2 properties using custom filter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter through multiple properties in Angular. I am able to filter through one property easily by using an angular `filter:{ title: searchString }` but to filter through a multiple properties... i created my own custom filter which tries to match the search string by any of the properties in the array.

What I need to do is:

If `John Wayne` is passed through.. it shows `John Wayne` but if only `John` or only `Wayne` is passed through... It still shows John Wayne. Similarly for `n w` since `John` ends with an `n` and `subTitle` starts with a `w`

**PS: I can only have one ng-model**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString">

<div ng-repeat="tel in arr1 | customFilter: searchString:['title','subTitle']"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.arr1 = [
    {title: 'John', subTitle:'Wayne'}
    {title: 'Barry'}
];

.filter('customFilter',[ function() {
    return function(items, searchText, attrs) {
        var filtered = [];
        var filteredItems = items.map(function(item) {
            angular.forEach(attrs, function(attr) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
        return filtered;
  };
}])
```

My issue is that I am getting an error saying:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys. Repeater: tel in arr1

Comment: You have an error in the name of your filter: customFilter in your filter name and custommFilter in your html

Comment: @ManuelObregozo whoops.. that was a typo. Accidentally inserted that in the post but thats not the issue

Comment: I still do get what it the idea of the filter, what is the output, of your array?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo basically... whatever is typed in the search field... i want it to be matched against all properties of the array

Comment: I think i got it, let me put all together in a plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a few updates to your custom filter:

```
app.filter('customFilter',[ function() {
    return function(items, searchText, attrs) {
        var filtered = []; 
        for (var i in items){
          var keepGoing = true;
          angular.forEach(attrs, function(attr) {
            console.log(items[i][attr])
                if (items[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) && items[i][attr].includes(searchText)  && keepGoing) {
                    filtered.push(items[i]);
                    keepGoing=false;
                }
            });
        }

        return filtered;
  };
}])
```

Take into account that in this case it is case-sensitive.

Although it is working as expected, I feel like it can be improved.

Plunker Sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YnkSSOpG8sBQvVChIIuP?p=preview

Comment: I tried that before as well :(... but in your example it doesn't work when i type "wayne"

Comment: which is what led me to creating a custom filter

Comment: the match condition could be a substring aswell?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YnkSSOpG8sBQvVChIIuP?p=preview seems to be working as expected, please check. take into account that it is case-sensitive. If you do not want it to be like that, just transform the item to lower case. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of duplicates in the `arr1`. Just add `track by $index` to achieve the desired solution

```
<div ng-repeat="tel in arr1 track by $index | custommFilter: searchString:['title','subTitle']"></div>
```

Comment: error is gone when i insert track by at the end... but now it doesn't do what i want it to do... it doesn't filter correctly

Comment: filter either with title or sub title at a time. How can you do with both at a time?